# Magento 2 - setDefaultOrder on Catalog pages

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog, sorting

I've added this to `category_category_view.xml` under `Magento_Catalog->layout` in my custom theme. It's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
    <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultOrder">
            <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="setDefaultDirection">
            <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

I can't find any examples of this for Magento 2 anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, we can use `<argument>` to pass an argument:http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php::_beforeToHtml*

```
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
```

We should reference to `product_list`, not `product_list_toolbar`. Our `catalog_category_view.xml` config should be:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list">
  <action method="setSortBy">
       <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
  </action>
  <action method="setDefaultDirection">
       <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
  </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I don't understand the argument names. They don't match anything. Should they be setDefaultOrder and setDefaultDirection instead?

Comment: You should take a look: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php::_beforeToHtml`. We can see the getting arguments.

Comment: This does not work for me. Can I not have a block and a reference block of the same name in my catelog_category_view.xml? I'm not sure what the issue could be. Also, could you explain why the argument name is "dir"?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.

```
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
            <action method="setSortBy">
                <argument name="sort" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
            </action>
     </block>
```

I was close originally, but instead of "dir" for the argument name, it needed to be "sort".